# Using grepl to extract a value from text across multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, plyr, grepl

I have a dataframe (df) containing 2 columns of data for state and city. Sometimes, however, the data inside the 2 columns are transposed or incorrectly entered. The dataframe will look something like this:

```
location          state
Bangkok
                  Bangkok Metropolitan
Central Thai      Bangkok
```

I want to create a new column, "City" by extracting 'Bangkok' from these two into a separate column. I can do this for one column by something like:

```
df$city <- ifelse(grepl("Bangkok",df$location),"Bangkok","")
```

However, I want to search at least 2 or more columns at once, something like:

```
df$city <- ifelse(grepl("Bangkok",df$location||df$state),"Bangkok","")
```

which, obviously, doesn't work. 'filter' in plyr I think does something similar but in reverse.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your expected output as well?  Is `Bangkok` the only string you will ever be searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` more than once. Besides, you should use `|` rather than `||`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(location=c("Bangkok", "",  "Central Thai", "someth"), 
                  state=c("", "Bangkok Metropolitan", "Bangkok", "youguess"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df1$city <- ifelse(grepl("Bangkok", df1$location) | grepl("Bangkok", df1$state),
                   "Bangkok","")
df1
#       location                state    city
# 1      Bangkok                      Bangkok
# 2              Bangkok Metropolitan Bangkok
# 3 Central Thai              Bangkok Bangkok
# 4       someth             youguess
```

See also ?"|"

**For |, & and xor a logical or raw vector.**

**For ||, && and isTRUE, a length-one logical vector.**

Answer (score 3):

You could also just paste the columns together

```
df$city <- ifelse(grepl("Bangkok", paste(df$location,df$state)),"Bangkok","")
```

Comment: Thanks for this also